# python - print output

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have created this below script and it works fine. But the output is not friendly (see below). I want the first line to display only the hostname and IP and remove (,'[], please suggest

```
('testhostname', [], ['10.10.10.10'])
cannot resolve hostname:  10.10.10.11
```

---

```
import socket
pfile = open ('C:\\Python27\\scripts\\test.txt')
while True:
    IP = pfile.readline()
    if not IP:
        break
    try:
        host = socket.gethostbyaddr(IP.rstrip())
        print host
    except socket.herror, err:
        print "cannot resolve hostname: ", IP
pfile.close()
```

Comment: @Thomas: `gethostbyaddr` does a reverse lookup and provides a hostname (along with aliases and alternative IPs), so it's not pointless. See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyaddr).

Comment: You're right, I'll delete my stupid comment.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than printing all of the `host` tuple that is returned by `gethostbyaddr`, I suggest unpacking into separate variables that you can then print as you see fit:

```
hostname, alias_list, ip_addr_list = gethostbyaddr(IP.rstrip())
print hostname, ip_addr_list # or ip_addr_list[0] if you only want the one IP
```

If you want more control over the formatting, I suggest using the `str.format` method:

```
print "hostname: {}, IP(s): {}".format(hostname, ", ".join(ip_addr_list))
```

Also, a few other code suggestions (not directly related to your main question):

- Use a `with` statement rather than manually opening and closing your file.
- Iterate on the file object directly (with `for IP in pfile:`), rather than using `while True:` and calling `pfile.readline()` each time through.
- Use the syntax `except socek.herror as err` rather than the older form with commas (which is deprecated in Python 2 and no longer exists in Python 3).